# Error handling with Http Outbound Gateway in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to understand how errors should be handled in Spring Integration. I found [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/archive/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/apbs04.html) about `errorChannel`, I tried to use it but the exception is not caught.

Here is my HTTP outbound gateway:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="orderRequestHttpGateway"
                               request-channel="orders-channel"
                               url="${url}"
                               http-method="POST"
                               expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                               reply-timeout='5000'
                               reply-channel='pushed-channel'
                               charset="UTF-8">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

I don't understand where I should catch exceptions thrown by this component (like a 500 HTTP error)

The route is started by a `poller`. I tried adding an `error-channel`property:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="orders-trigger-channel" expression="''">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="${poller}" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I tried with a custom error channel. I also tried to override the existing errorChannel:

```
<int:channel id="errorChannel"/>
<int:outbound-channel-adapter id="errorChannelHandler"
                               ref="errorManager"
                               method="foo"
                               channel="errorChannel"/>
```

So far I keep getting `MessageHandlingException` and I can't catch them to deal with them properly.

Answer (score 1):

You catch exception only in the caller thread or in the place where you have a `try...catch` - there is nothing different in Spring Integration from pure Java: we catch exception whenever we have a `try...catch`.

According your description, the `error-channel="errorChannel"` on the `<poller>` is the way to go and if you don't have any other thread shifting downstream, such a `MessageHandlingException` is really thrown to the poller and wrapped into the `ErrorMessage` to be sent to that `errorChannel` configured.

It is a `MessageHandlingException` because we deal with the `Messaging` in Spring Integration and such an exception carries some context and important information about the flow and failed message. Your `500 HTTP error` is just a `cause` in that message. So, when you catch and handle an `ErrorMessage` you should take a look into its stack trace for the information to parse.

On the other hand you can narrow a scope for the error handling via `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` or `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Answer (score 0):

**Int-http:outbound-gateway** has **error-handler** by default,You can use this error-handler to handle error of out bound. in your example add error-handler to int-http:outbound-gateway with sample name of errorHandler class name like below:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="orderRequestHttpGateway"
                               request-channel="orders-channel"
                               url="${url}"
                               http-method="POST"
                               expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                               reply-timeout='5000'
                               reply-channel='pushed-channel'
                               charset="UTF-8"
                               error-handler="nameOfErrorHandler">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Then create new class with nameOfErrorHandler that extend **DefaultResponseErrorHandler** like below

```
@Component("nameOfErrorHandler")
public class NameOfErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {
    public NameOfErrorHandler() {
    }

    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Custom Message");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Custom Message");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE) {
            throw new ChannelsLimitExceededException("Custom Message");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED) {
            throw new PerTransactionLimitExceeded("Custom Message");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT) {
            throw new DailyLimitExceededException("Custom Message");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CONFLICT) {
            throw new MonthlyLimitExceeded("Custom Message");
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.GONE) {
            throw new DuplicateReqIdException("Custom Message");
        } else {
            throw new AccessInternalException("Internal server error");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This all throw new some exceptions catch by first error-channel defined in chain